# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "hibernate_sequence"

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a `import.sql` in my `resources` folder to import initial data to my Postgres database with Hibernate.

Now this works perfectly with a statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO event (id, date, time, name) VALUES (0, '2021-06-02', '16:00', 'Test');
```

However, the id is annotated with `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` and should be auto incremented. When preloading data like this I get a primary key violation when adding more data through my application.

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO event (id, date, time, name) VALUES (hibernate_sequence.NEXTVAL, '2021-06-02', '16:00', 'Test');

INSERT INTO event (id, date, time, name) VALUES (nextval('hibernate_sequence'), '2021-06-02', '16:00', 'Test');
```

but both didn't work, I'm just getting this error.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "hibernate_sequence"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove id insertion at all.
I think the reason is that you have table specific sequence, that can produce new id for each new insertions

INSERT INTO event (date, time, name) VALUES ('2021-06-02', '16:00', 'Test');